# How to "use a component as icon" in google maps api / React.js

Tags: reactjs, google-maps

I can't use a component - *a simple one, just a div with a h1 inside that renders the price for the marker*-

I want to emulate the price icon marker from AirBnB

I've tried with the marker icon proerty, even with the content property.

It work for the infoWindow, but I couldn't make it for the icon

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/custom-markers

I tried this, works with an image, but not with a Component

```
 const markerCreator = coords => {
      const marker = new maps.Marker({
        position: {
          lat: coords.latitud,
          lng: coords.longitud,
        },
        map,
        title: 'Hello World!',
        icon: `${iconBase}parking_lot_maps.png`,
      });
      const infoWindow = new maps.InfoWindow({
        content: ReactDOMServer.renderToString(<Test>{coords.latitud}</Test>),
      });

      marker.addListener('click', function() {
        // map.setZoom(8);
        // map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    };
```

I want to render a custom icon, but It won't be an image, It will be a Component, a simple div with some text inside, like the AirBnb icons that displays the price.

Comment: How about adding a custom Popup instead of a marker, you can check the detail in here: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/overlay-popup

Comment: when you use images from your local app and not from a link: http/... use always **require('path/to')**

Comment: `icon: require(\`${iconBase}parking_lot_maps.png\`)`

Comment: I'll give it a try to the popup solution.

For the image path, I'm just using that part of code from the google maps api docs, I will not render an image, I want to render a Component, as I said in the question